# Scikit Learn Latent Dirichlet Allocation overload my SWAP and/or RAM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

1) After using [LDA of scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) I realized it overloads the swap, but never reach more than 20% of the RAM. Do you have any idea why ? I can't really see if this is a problem, but still I would like to understand what happens in memory !

2) The parallelization of this algorithm (using parameter n_jobs=-1) leads to memory errors on my server (192 GB of RAM, 32 CPU cores). I think this is due to the fact that parallelization uses forks to create threads, leading to copying 32 time the current memory (which can be quite big if data are loaded in memory). How could I improve this ?

[image: A screen shot of my server's state when i launched LDA (n_jobs=1) around 16:00]